# How to monitor ECS tasks which are not registered on ELB?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have services that interact over messaging and are not required to be registered on a load balancer. For health check, I have configured [container healthcheck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html) and I have verified that it all works. But I am not able to find a way to monitor these services -  how do I create alarms and notifications when the tasks become unhealthy or go below the desired count? For other tasks registered on ALB, I have alarms for 'HealthyHostCount' metric.

I tried creating Eventbridge rule to receive notifications when a task stops by following this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html) but I am not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: Container health checks are definitely the way to go.  Q: What (if anything) have you seen "fail" despite the corresponding [AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition HealthCheck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-healthcheck.html) being reported as "HEALTHY"?  Q: If you've seen such occurrences, did you ever determine the root cause?

Comment: There can be rare occurrences where healthcheck is healthy but service will service would not work e.g. Rabbitmq memory threshold crossing. My aim is however to be notified for simpler cases where healthcheck fails and restarting tasks by ECS won't resolve the issue.

Comment: The EventBridge notifications for container health checks you have configured is absolutely the correct way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I see two issues with Eventbridge notifications, 1. It will keep sending new emails for each task restart in case of an unhealthy task until the issue gets fixed 2. There will be no history like we can get for Cloudwatch metric alarms.